# MSBuild - how to tell at compile time if a file exists and use it?

Tags: c++, msbuild

I am using MSBuild (recent), windows 10, to compile a C++ vcxproj file. During the compile, I need to use a giant dependencies folder. If the file exists locally to the build, I want to reference that one. If it doesn't exist locally, I want to use the folder pointed to in a system variable. I would like to set this up somehow in a .props file and include it, but I have no idea where to start.

Ideas? I don't want to use a .BAT file to shell out and set variables.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Exists condition function? You would have two instances of the variable, one where the condition is true, the other where it is not.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyDependency Condition="Exists('LocalDir')">LocalDir</MyDependency>
  <MyDependency Condition="!Exists('LocalDir')">$(REMOTE_DIR)</MyDependency>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can just use the Exists macro. Furthermore, i suggest that you also do a check for empty string. This allows you to override the default setting on build time:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyDependency Condition="'$(MyDependency)'==''">$(SystemVariable)</MyDependency>
  <!-- You can even use regsitry Values as default -->
  <MyDependency Condition="'$(MyDependency)'==''">$([MSBuild]::GetRegistryValue('HKEY_Local_Machine\...','KEYNAME')</MyDependency>
  <MyDependency Condition="Exists('LocalDir')">LocalDir</MyDependency>
</PropertyGroup>
```